# Using Yahoo Finance API to obtain the stock price at a particluar time?

Tags: python, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am developing Stock tracking software in Python. I am able to obtain the price of a given stock on a current day. Given a stock, I am able to obtain the real time price of that stock.

For analysis purpose, I am trying to obtain the price of a given stock on a particular day.

For example, is it possible that I can obtain the stock price of Apple (AAPL) on May 5th, 2015 at 11.30AM ?

I can get the data from Yahoo finance through the interactive chart tool : http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=AAPL+Interactive#{"allowChartStacking":true}

I was wondering, if we have the API to do the same.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The short answer with a quick google result is yes [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4). While you can use this API, Chris reeves go through datamining specifically the stock exchange in his tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7wB__M9fdw). What I prefer to use is (scrapy)[http://scrapy.org/]. There are other options including but not limited to BeautifulSoup4 and urllib. Each has its own strengths and weaknesses but I prefer Scrapy as I use it the most.

Comment: Following your first link, I don't see anything which can get historical data at a given time. In fact I think the answer is no

Comment: In their documentation there is this function.  print yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29').

Comment: Yes but that only gives the daily data (high, low, close, volume, ...), not the data at a certain time of day e.g. May 5th, 2015 at 11.30AM